# Bernoulli and ideal flows

Tags: fluid-dynamics

The question states that there is a permanent source of liquid at the bottom of a given reservoir and I need to find the maximum elevation of the liquid surface given two cases: $1.$ a straight narrow slit with a constant flux per unit length and $2.$ a point-like source. I know that I need to use Bernoulli's equation here and somehow equate something to "intensity" of flux, but I do not know exactly how to proceed with it. Could I get the rough steps to how must I proceed with the problem?

**Some simplifications that I thought to adopt:** Neglect surface tension (because I wasn't able to understand/visualize the effect of surface tension-would there be more boundary conditions at the interface?). The interface is stationary and the flow is potential.

Comment: Are the sides of the reservoir involved or are we treating this as basically infinite (much wider than it is deep)?

Comment: I presume it is much wider than is deep ...